# Can't get Extra from specific activity

Tags: android

I have a very weird problem.
I know how to pass data from an intent to another using PutExtra/getExtras.
When i wanted to get the data passed between the two intents ,it gets NullPointerException.
I have tried to achieve that too by passing a bundle, the same problem happened.
So i tried to pass it to another activity , and it is passed!!
Why the first activity couldn't retrieve the data passed ?!

Comment: can you post some code? there are many possible reasons for this

Comment: Show related part of code for sending/getting data using Intent/Bundle from both Activities

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: I posted some code :)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

ActivityA:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("identifier", "some text");
startActivity(i);
```

ActivityB:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String string = intent.getStringExtra("identifier");    //String because your extra is a String value
```

Have you done it like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did.

From IntentServiceClass:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, class1);
    intent.putExtra("test", "test");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity (context, 0, intent, 0);
```

From Activity Class:

```
String test = getIntent().getExtras().getString("test");
```

It causes NullPointerException

After many times of testing , i created a new activity and copy/paste the same code , and it worked!!
So i'm asking why didn't it work with the first class ??

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have three activity A B C
In order to get intent from A to B use put Extra(content) and to get the same data from A to C use putExtras(get intent) in B and in C use getExtra(content). I was also having the same null point exception untill I searched and tried everything and got this solution

Comment: Please include some code examples of your solution, as this is a new answer to an old question, please be sure to specifically address how your answer is different or better than the other 2 posted in 2015. you answer sounds compelling, add the code examples to demonstrate your ideas in full.